# Run Phone Apps in VM Anonymously and Security Risks of Virtualbox

Tags: linux, exploit, tor, virtualization, phone

Would it be possible to run phone apps that connect to the internet (eg. youtube, instagram, etc.) on an Android VM (or any sort of phone VM, doesn't need to be android) in VirtualBox within a host OS such as Tails or Whonix so that they can be run at least pseudonymously? I was thinking using the android ISO.

I'm just concerned that this might not be anonymous enough and that there might be serious security issues with android in a VM.

One possible issue might be that VirtualBox is pretty vulnerable. However, as I understand it,  the risk is mitigated if I run a VirtualBox *inside* a system that funnels all traffic through Tor--then there is little risk an attacker could see my IP correct? Are there other implications regarding VirtualBox vulnerability?

Any relevant responses would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Virtual machines and emulators by themselves do not really add any kind of anonymity. Using VPN or similar technologies (i.e. Tor) hide at least your current public IP address. But hiding only the public IP is far from being anonymous.

If you are for example logged into the apps or have associated an account with the Android system then none of these technologies will hide this. Even if you've created a new account specifically for this purpose it will at least be possible to track activities done with this account and thus create a profile of the user which (depending on how long the account is used and for how many activities) might be enough to narrow down who this person might be.

Comment: Thanks. Yea, the VM was just to run Android rather than to add anonimity. And I'm planning on using only one application and not connecting anything about my real identity to it: even not using the same words/typing patterns as I do usually, to divorce it from my identity. A user called forest made a post a while ago and mentioned this article: https://hsmr.cc/palinopsia/ to prove that virtualbox isn't safe--I was sort of wondering how to mitigate that threat in this scenario (and, to be frank, I have trouble understanding what the author of the article concludes).

Comment: @YellowBellow: The attack described there is practically irrelevant for your use case.

Comment: I really appreciate your replies, thank you. Would I be correct in saying that the attack would apply to my use case if the attacker either got physical control of my laptop or if my host OS was personally related to me? Otherwise, I can just ignore it?

Comment: @YellowBellow: Yes, but if the attacker got that far you are likely no longer anonymous anyway. In theory the attacker might also find a bug in the Android App and a bug in the Android OS to get root permissions and somehow combine this with the issue in Virtualbox - highly unlikely. Of course, your actual risk depends on the what threats you have to fear, which is totally unclear from your question.